# Ignore a file's changes, but include it in the repository

Tags: git, github

I know this may seem, or be an existing question, but in most of the previous questions I found, people tended to discourage this behavior, often bringing up the -justified- argument that "if git doesn't do it, maybe you shouldn't either".

I'm using git not for pure software development, but also to track a power system modelling tool's collaborative progress. Our work with the repository consists of both direct scripting/modification of text files, but also some GUI-based work (the third-party software modifies the files).

The issue is, there is a initialization file containing no significant information (let's call it model.ini), but still necessary for the software to execute in "GUI-mode". Every time someone manually saves the model (through the software's GUI), there is an actual line in the file "model.ini" that tracks the last-saved timestamp, and inevitably gets modified.

The "model.ini" file is necessary for the software to launch, but I have it in .gitignore, to avoid trivial conflicts about last-time-saved. So, when I push to our github repo, this file is skipped, so other colleagues (which by the way are not much experienced about how git works, so a CLI-based solution wouldn't be of much help), they need to manually copy-paste it to launch the software.

Overall it's a minor discomfort, but I'd be happier if I could keep ignoring the "model.ini" file, while also including it in pushes/pulls.

I tried various solutions, but unfortunately, if it's not a relatively simple, once-and-for all command/config setting, it won't work, since my colleagues are using git through GitHub Desktop, and a recurring CLI-based approach wouldn't be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

The [Git FAQ is very clear](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files) that you can't ignore tracked files in Git:

> Git doesn’t provide a way to do this. The reason is that if Git needs to overwrite this file, such as during a checkout, it doesn’t know whether the changes to the file are precious and should be kept, or whether they are irrelevant and can safely be destroyed. Therefore, it has to take the safe route and always preserve them.
>
> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

The answer the Git FAQ gives is that you need to ignore the file, like you're doing now, and store the actual file elsewhere.  There can be a simple setup script (which you could call `setup`) which copies it in place, and it can be as simple as double-clicking the script from the normal OS folder interface (whatever that is on your system).  On Linux or macOS, that could be an executable shell script; I'll leave the way to solve it on Windows as an exercise to the reader.

You could also adjust the software not to include the last-saved timestamp, which would avoid the file being needlessly modified.  In general, many software projects are moving away from embedded timestamps in the interests of reproducible builds, so this may be a simple and easy way to solve the problem.